# Количество чисел после запятой в ADOTable

Tags: access, delphi

Здравствуйте!

Как отобразить число с двумя знаками после запятой?

К примеру, у меня БД `Access->ADOConnection->ADOTable->DataSource->DBGrid`... В столбце DBgrid отображаются силовые данные в формате 795,090026855469... Хотя в конструкторе Access выставлено:

- Тип - числовой,
- Размер поля - Одинарное с плавающей точкой,
- Формат поля - денежный,
- Число десятичных знаков - 2,

и отображает соответственно верно, а вот в DBGrid иначе...  Что надо сделать, чтоб было 795,09?

Спасибо)

Comment: Да, вы явно попали не на тот форум ВиО :) Delphi давно вымирает и много людей уже не знают таких тонкостей, а может и вовсе ничего о дельфях.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Одним из способов получения контроля над характеристиками DBGrid или другими компонентами является создание статического набора компонентов TField. Имея компонент типа TField, созданный для каждого из полей в наборе данных, можно установить ширину, формат, маску, расположение, метку для отображения в DBGrid и другие характеристики.

Источник - [CITForum.ru](http://citforum.ru/programming/application/glava1_4.shtml).

В свойстве DisplayFormat выбранного поля (компонента TField) пишем 0.00 и получаем нужный эффект.

Comment: @Leshij_2005 Зачем эта цитата?

Comment: Должно быть, это правильный ответ :) Или что-то, что навело автора на правильный ответ.

Comment: @cy6erGn0m это правильный ответ;) По крайней мере работает и результат на лицо)

Answer (score 1):

Задайте формат данных поля dbgrid, если это возможно.

Альтернативный (и более правильный) вариант - храните данные в том виде, который имеет смысл. Если 795.0900268 и так далее - это сумма денег, то лишние цифры можно смело выкинуть - все равно они не имею физического смысла, а вот при сложении множества подобных чисел могут дать расхождения в копейках, что не позволит сдать документы в какую-нибудь инстанцию.

Answer (score 1):

А может ещё при сохранении записывать в БД число с 2 числами после запятой?
Вот объявляем функцию:

```
function RoundEx(chislo: double; Precision: Integer): string;
var 
    ChisloInStr: string; 
    ChisloInCurr: currency; 
begin
    ChisloInCurr := chislo;
    Str(ChisloInCurr: 20:
    Precision, ChisloInStr);  
    ChisloInStr[Pos('.', ChisloInStr)] := ',';
    RoundEx := Trim(ChisloInStr);
end;
```

А уже в процедуре вызываем после расчётов:

```
a:=StrToInt(kol1.Text); // ну это значение в одном поле
b:=StrToFloat(stom1.Text); // ну это значение во втором поле
c:=a*b; // здесь получаем определённое число
sum1.Text:=RoundEx((c), 2); // а здесь это число мы форматируем как надо - два знака после запятой
```

А потом просто это значение добавляем в БД.